# Android how to change contents of edittext in real time

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am looking to make an app which converts one unit to another(say currency). So it consists of 2 edit-texts. One in which the user enters the value and the second which contains the result. Now, here, instead of having a 'convert' button to put the value in the second edit text, i would like the converted value to appear in the second edit text AS I ENTER VALUES INTO THE FIRST ONE. How can i achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `TextWatcher` for this. Set it on the `EditText` that the user types in:

```
myEditText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        String value = s.toString();

                        // Perform computations using this string
                        // For example: parse the value to an Integer and use this value

                        // Set the computed value to the other EditText
                        myEditText2.setText(computedValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {             

        }

    });
```

**Edit 1**:

Check for empty string `""`:

```
myEditText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String value = s.toString();

        if (value.equals("")) {
            myEditText1.setText("0");

            // You may not need this line, because "myEditText1.setText("0")" will
            // trigger this method again and go to else block, where, if your code is set up
            // correctly, myEditText2 will get the value 0. So, try without the next line
            // and if it doesn't work, put it back.
            myEditText2.setText("0");
        } else {

            // Perform computations using this string
            // For example: parse the value to an Integer and use this value

            // Set the computed value to the other EditText
            myEditText2.setText(computedValue);
        }
}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){              

    }

});
```

Comment: yes this works. but for example i enter the value in dollar to be converted to rupee as 23. it gives the correct output. then if i press the back button to change it to first remove '3'. then finally if i try to remove '2' as well, then it crashes. I would like it to change to 0 dollar and 0 rupee if i empty the first edittext. How do i do that?

Comment: Yes, this happens because `onTextChanged(CharSequence, int, int, int)` is triggered whenever text inside `myEditText1` changes. You have to check for empty string `""`. See **Edit 1** above.

Comment: @ShivamBhalla You are probably getting a `NumberFormatException`. **Edit 1** above should solve your problem.

Comment: i tried that but i am still facing the same issue with numberformatexception invalid double:""

Comment: any thoughts on that?

Comment: @ShivamBhalla Can you edit your question and post your code? It'll be easier to figure out the problem that way.